# Objective-C NSNumber Value From Entity Property

Tags: objective-c, nsnumber

Im successfully pulling a number from a entity. But if I init that number with an NSNnumber, it seems a random number is generated...

```
//This code works, and I can write the number to the NSLOG ok.
Misc_RandomNumber *rndNum = [fetchedObjects objectAtIndex:0];
NSLog(@"%@",rndNum.randomNumber); //Log will print the number 1

//From here, numberFound will result to a random number like 2064127
NSNumber *numberFound = [NSNumber numberWithInt:rndNum.randomNumber];
NSLog(@"%@",[numberFound stringValue]);
```

I just need that database value in an NSNumber, cant seem to get it.

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error on the second sentences, when you do

```
NSNumber *numberFound = [NSNumber numberWithInt:rndNum.randomNumber];
```

In this case `[NSNumber numberWithInt:rndNum.randomNumber];` is returning you the address where the `randomNumber` is, not the value it is pointing to. Instead you should use:

```
NSNumber *numberFound = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[rndNum.randomNumber intValue]];
```